# Focus on input and autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, blur

I have a `<div>` with `contenteditable=true`. I attach a blur event so the input get recorded once the user leaves the field:

```
$(document).on('#my_div'n 'blur', function () {.......
```

I attach to this field a jquery autocomplete:

```
$('#my_div').autocomplete({ source : emails_directory   });
```

The autocomplete works well and fills in the field when clicked.

The problem here is that my blur event record only the first letters that I typed before triggering the autocomplete.

What event should I use in order to record the field value if autocomplete isn't used, or the value of the autocomplete if used.

Ex: 
I want to get test@mail.com from the autocomplete.
I type 'te' and the full email displays in the autocomplete. 
I select it in the autocomplete list and it is filled in the field.
My blur event records 'te'. I dont want that and would like to record test@mail.com instead

Ex2:
I want to enter a value which is not in the autocomplete source.
I type new_email@mail.com, no autocomplete displays.
On blur the full value is recorded.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger keydown event for ENTER on blur. So you can get the autocomplete value if exists:

```
$(document).on('#my_div', 'blur', function () {
         var keyEvent = $.Event("keydown");
         keyEvent.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.ENTER;
         $(this).trigger(keyEvent);
         ......
});
```

and also dont forget autofocus:

```
$('#my_div').autocomplete(autoFocus: true, { source : emails_directory });
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't get it. You can select the autocomplete also by clicking, would it still trigger a ENTER keydown?

Comment: Yes but it shouln't change anything. Value would stay the same